# Programmatically Query Azure Application Insights Analytics

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

Based off [Overview of log queries in Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/log-query-overview), is there any method to programmatically query using .NET the application insights analytics and download the results?

Like say something like this in my C# application:

```cs
application_insight_analytics.connect(ApplicationInsightsConnectionString)
application_insight_analytics.query(query).toList();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Full Application Insights API is available, details are here:

https://dev.applicationinsights.io/

Comment: link doesn't work anymore. Update would be welcomed.