# Accessing Application Insights Analytics from either Insights or .net

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I heave created a query in (the wonderful tool ) Application Insight Analytics which I intended to use for monitoring in one way or another, but from what I found, this is not that easy?

The query returns some data I would like to set up Application Insight alerts on (such as if (column1 equals '1') then alert() or if(column2 > 10) then alert().

Or if that is not possible, is the Analytics service available either from .net code or power shell? If so, I would be able to create the alert-service myself (not ideal though).

Is any of the above features available?

(I do not think the functionality I´m after is available in Insights. I want to compare two custom events and based on differences between them, take actions if necessary)

Comment: There is a thread about accessing it through code (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836090/programatically-query-azure-application-insights-analytics) but that is my least desired solution (and it is not available yet), since It would require me to host the functionality in a web job or similar.

Comment: you should explore function apps

Answer (score 1):

There's *currently* no way to get azure alerts from an Analytics query.

However, there is a request for that on uservoice:
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/14428134-add-alerts-based-on-results-of-analytics-queries

so go upvote and comment on that to make your voice heard.

There's also a planned service to read data from Analytics through an API as well:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/4999529-make-data-accessible-via-apis-for-custom-processin

Which you could write your own service against to do extra work.